# Computability of sets of fixed point values

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Recall that [Rogers' fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Rogers.27_fixed-point_theorem) states that, if $f$ is a total computable function, then it has a *fixed point value*, i.e., there is an index $i$ such that $\varphi_i\simeq\varphi_{f(i)}$.

**My question is what is known about the recursiveness and recursive enumerability of the set of fixed point values of $f$.**

I can prove, for instance, that if the [orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Abelian_property_and_Iteration_sequences) (under $f$) of each index has finite complement (with respect to $\mathbb N$), then the set of fixed point values of $f$ is not recursive. The techniques I used have been around since the works of Kleene, hence my results should be well known. Still, I was unable to find any discussion on this topic in the relevant literature, except for a couple of exercises on Rogers' and Odifreddi's monographs, which seem to hint at a well-developed theory, but provide no specific references.

Any pointers?

**EDIT:**  to make my question more concrete, let us focus on the function $f=\lambda x.x+1$. I know that the set $F$ of the fixed point values of $f$ is not recursive, for any admissible numbering of computable functions. What about recursive enumerability? Are there two admissible numberings that make $F$ r.e. and not r.e., respectively?

Comment: I am pretty sure that using the fact that $\{e : \varphi_e \text{ is total}\}$ is $\Pi^0_2$ complete, one can also show that the set of fix points for a given total computable $F$ is $\Pi^0_2$ and moreover there exists some total computable $F$ such that the set of $F$-fixed points is $\Pi^0_2$ complete.  (I don't however know if every $\Pi^0_2$ set is the set of fixed points of some total computable $F$. That is a more difficult.)

Comment: This reminds me of a cute paper I saw recently, John Case & Michael Ralston, *Non-obfuscated unprovable programs & many resultant subtleties*, Log. Methods Comput. Sci. 12 (2016), no. 2, 2:2, 25 pp. https://lmcs.episciences.org/1634, which deals with a very similar issue (and relates it to provability).

Answer (score 3):

In general, the question of whether a given program $i$ is a
fixed-point with respect to a given computuble function $f$, has
complexity $\Pi^0_2$. And for some functions, it is
$\Pi^0_2$-complete.

First, it is easy to see that the assertion that $i$ is a fixed
point with respect to $f$, meaning that $\varphi_i=\varphi_{f(i)}$, has
complexity at most $\Pi^0_2$, since $i$ is a fixed point just in
case for every converging instance of one of the functions, there
is a corresponding converging instance of the other with the same
output value.

Conversely, let me provide a computable function $f$ for which the
fixed-point set is $\Pi^0_2$-complete. Fix a $\Pi^0_2$-universal
set $U$, where $x\in U$ if and only if $\forall k\
\exists j\ A(x,k,j)$, where $A$ is $\Delta_0$. Define $f$ as
follows. For each $i$, let $f(i)$ be a program undertaking the
following procedure: first, let $x=\varphi_i(0)$; now, on input
$k$, search for $j$ for which $A(x,k,j)$, and output $x$ if found;
otherwise keep searching.

For any $x$, let $e_x$ be a program that is known to compute
constant value $x$. Observe that $x\in U$ just in case $f(e_x)$
computes the constant value $x$. Thus, $x\in U$ if and only if
$e_x$ computes the same function as $f(e_x)$, which is to say, if
and only if $e_x$ is a fixed point with respect to $f$.

So for this function, the fixed-point set is $\Pi^0_2$-complete. In
particular, it is not c.e.

**Update.** Meanwhile, let us consider your updated question,
focussed on the particular function $s(x)=x+1$. I claim that there
is an admissible enumeration of computable functions for which the fixed-point question for this function is
is not c.e. Suppose for example that we have an encoding where odd
numbers always encode the empty function. (Many of the naturally
occurring encodings of Turing machines or whatever have this
property, if you use, say, prime powers for sequence encoding or
$2^n(2m+1)$-type pairing functions, since odd numbers wouldn't code
things as usual, and the corresponding enumerated computable
function $\varphi_k$ for $k$ odd would be the empty function by
default.) Thus, a fixed point $\varphi_e=\varphi_{e+1}$ for the
successor function in this case would involve at least one odd
index, and so it would be the empty function. Thus, an index $e$ is
a fixed point if and only if $e$ is even and $\varphi_e$ is the
empty function, or $e$ is odd and $\varphi_{e+1}$ is the empty
function. This is easily seen to be co-c.e. and $\Pi^0_1$-complete,
using methods as in my answer above. Basically, it is equivalent to
the emptiness problem, which is $\Pi^0_1$-complete. In particular, it is not c.e.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I already knew, because both Rogers and Odifreddi have this exercise.  But my question was more general.  Let us forget about pathological functions and take, for instance, $\lambda x.x+1$.  I can prove that the set of fixed point values of this $f$ is not recursive.  Is it recursively enumerable?  What about $\lambda x.x+2$?  Are there general theorems about the fixed point values of these functions?

Comment: I think that if you are looking at specific functions like that, the answer could depend on the particular way that you represent computable functions by their indices. That is, the answers in those cases may depend on what are usually otherwise considered irrelevant syntactic details.

Comment: The acceptable numberings of partial computable functions are pretty robust, why do you think the answers may depend? For instance, the indices of the fixed points of $\lambda x . x + 1$, how could they depend on the numbering in an essential way?

Comment: Because the question is not just about the function that the index computes, but it is allowed to ask about the index itself. That is why Rice's theorem, for example, does not apply here. For example, for some enumerations it may be that odd numbers always compute the empty function, and in this case, to decide fixed points of the function $f(i)=2i+1$ will be equivalent to the empty-function problem.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well.  But on the other hand, the theorem I gave above (i.e., if all orbits have finite complement, then the fixed point set is not recursive) is pretty general, and applies to $\lambda x.x+1$ and any admissible numbering. This suggests that there may be something deeper going on. Are you telling me that this theorem was not known, and that there is no general theory that includes it?

Comment: Well, the fact that I haven't heard of the result certainly doesn't mean that it hasn't been looked at by others.

Comment: I read the Update.  Yes, I happened to know that part, too...  :D  Now, can you find a numbering that makes the set recursively enumerable?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer already does. My answer is that for my numbering, it isn't recursively enumerable. It is co-c.e. and $\Pi^0_1$-complete, and hence not c.e.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'recursively enumerable'.  I corrected my comment.

Comment: recursively enumerable is the same thing as c.e. (=computably enumerable).  So I think I've answered your updated question.

Comment: No, the updated question also asks for an admissible numbering that makes the set recursively enumerable.  Can you show me any?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, a friend showed me one such numbering. Now everything about x+1 is settled: the set of its fixed points is never recursive, but could be r.e. or not r.e. depending on the numbering.  However, the general problem remains open and very interesting, IMHO.

Comment: It would be kind of you to post the construction. It is fine in such a case to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: But also, to my way of thinking about it, if the result does indeed depend on the way we number the programs, then as I mentioned earlier, it suggests that the question is not actually natural, but is instead depending on unimportant syntactic details.

Comment: Yes, but as I'm trying to point out since the beginning, _some_ of these questions do _not_ depend on unimportant syntactic details. For instance, that the set of fixed points of x+k cannot be recursive is still a remarkable fact.  Hence the question: can we extend this result?  Can we characterize the functions whose fixed point sets have some inherent complexity?
Anyway, the construction that my friend showed me is not trivial and I do not know if I am allowed to publish it... All I can do is invite him to contribute to this discussion directly.  Sorry...